# Catalog access method clarification

Tags: macros, sas

I have stored the macro in a local working directory as shown
[image]

I would like to access the macro with following code:

```
libname test 'C:\Users\Desktop\Enhancement\';
filename prtsort catalog 'TEST.SASMACR';
%include prtsort(Printtext) ;
```

WHile it gives following error:

```
ERROR: Entry PRINTTEXT.SOURCE not found in catalog TEST.SASMACR.
ERROR: Cannot %INCLUDE member Printtext in the aggregate PRTSORT.
ERROR: Entry PRINTTEXT.SOURCE not found in catalog TEST.SASMACR.
ERROR: Cannot %INCLUDE member Printtext in the aggregate PRTSORT.
```

Anyone can delight me, which part i did wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to re-use stored compiled macros that have previously been saved in your folder then you don't need to `%include` them from the catalogue. After defining your libref `test` pointing to the folder, you just need to set

```
option mstored sasmstore = test;
```

and your session should pick up all macros stored there automatically.